# Is there a general procedure for covariantizing equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, covariance

I am currently attempting to derive covariant forms of equations whose domains are D=3 space.  I am considering Lorentzian $(\mathbb{R}^4, \Omega, x, \nabla)$, where $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^4$ has a psuedo-Riemannian metric $(g_{\mu\nu}) = diag(-1,1,1,1)$, and the quantities within my original D=3 equations are the magnetic field B and a fluid velocity field v.

Here is an example:  consider the non-covariant $$B\cdot\nabla\kappa=0.$$
In the covariant equations, B is now part of the gauge field strength tensor F where we identify
$$B_i= \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{ijk}F^{jk}$$ to obtain $$\varepsilon^{ijk}F_{jk}\nabla_i\kappa=0 $$

before setting $\varepsilon_{0ijk}=\varepsilon_{ijk}$, $E_i=F_{i0}$ and then passing to 
$$\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}\nabla_\mu\kappa_\nu=0.$$

I know  that we must identify non-covariant scalar functions $\kappa$ with the time components of a corresponding 4-vector $\kappa$.  Further, I am guessing that the old velocity field will have to become part of a tensor just as E and B become parts of F in order to properly account for their mixing.

When I look for examples of covariant generalizations, it seems as though authors draw upon a set of rules that I cannot find.  If anyone knows anything about the procedure for forming covariant forms of electromagnetic equations, that would be much appreciated.  Furthermore, if anyone has any idea of how to derive the relativistic forms of fluid equations, that would be even more appreciated.

p.s. can one even "covariantize" fields like a fluid's velocity field that do not come from gauge theories?

Thanks!

Comment: As a relativistic fluid dynamics person who works almost exclusively with non-relativists, I think this is a great question. Unfortunately I've never written down an algorithm for how I go about this sort of thing. I'll have to think about it, but perhaps there is something to be said for going into the fluid rest frame...

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform interesting indeed, but only helpful in showing how hard this problem is ;) @ChrisWhite  thank you! I have no prior experience in relativistic fluids, and have very little experience in fluids at all.  If it helps, here is what I have: an argument developing the class of fluid motions (by manipulating the velocity field) that yields a stress tensor for the fluid.